# XSL: add a link to a substring within a string made of several TEI-XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, tei

Since few days, I try to add a link to substring `w[@type='verb']` within a string.
I am working on a `TEI-XML` transliteration of clay tablets, thus `elements` and `@type` of `<w>` contained in `<l>` are not always in the same order.

`XSLT` version 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//div1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//div1">
<!-- additional content before <ul> -->
 <ul>
  <li>
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::lg/l[@n]">
       <xsl:variable name="verb1" select="w[@type='verb']"/>
       <xsl:variable name="href1" select="w[@type='verb']/@lemmaRef"/>
       <xsl:variable name="single-l" select="w[@type='coo'] | w[@type='noun'] | w[@type='verb'] | w[@type='num'] | w[@type='adv'] | w[@type='adj'] | g | name"/>

       <xsl:value-of select="$single-l"/> 
       <sup><xsl:value-of select="./@n"/></sup>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </li>
 </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to add a link `lemmaRef` for each `w[@type='verb']`.

A sample of `TEI` — I removed `@xml:id` from `element` other than `l` for this example:

```
<lg>
    <l n="4b-5a" xml:id="ktu1-3_ii_l4b-5a">
       <w type="coo">w</w><space/>
       <w type="verb" lemmaRef="uga/verb.xsl#qry"><damage degree="medium" facs="definir"><supplied resp="KTU">t</supplied></damage>qry</w>
       <g>.</g>
       <w type="noun" lemmaRef="uga/noun.xsl#ġlm">ġlmm</w>
       <lb/><w>b</w><space/>
       <w type="noun" lemmaRef="uga/noun.xsl#št">št</w>
       <g>.</g>
       <w type="noun" lemmaRef="uga/noun.xsl#ġr">ġr</w>
       <g>.</g>
    </l>
 </lg>
```

I need to display:

```
<ul>
 <li>w <a href="uga/verb.xml#qry">tqry</a> . ġlmm št . ġr .<sup>4b-5a</sup></li>
</ul>
```

"tqry" is a verb contained in `<l>`.

How can I do in `XSLT` to be able to display `<a href="{$href1}"><xsl:value-of select="$verb1"/>`. I tried `replace` of `$single-l` or to define a new variable of the previous `XSLT` code, but it doesn't work. I have tried also with `key` but I think I still have a problem of undertanding...

In advance, thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should try to build a string and then to insert markup there, it seems it should be possible to simply process the child elements and then match on the `lg/l[@n]/w[@type = 'verb']` to transform it to a HTML hyperlink:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div">
      <section>
          <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select=".//lg/l[@n]"/>
          </ul>
      </section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lg/l[@n]">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <sup>
              <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
          </sup>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lg/l[@n]/w[@type = 'verb']">
      <a href="{@lemmaRef}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="space">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This currently does not quite produce the wanted result but

```
<li>w <a href="uga/verb.xsl#qry">tqry</a>.ġlmmb št.ġr.<sup>4b-5a</sup></li>
```

instead but if there is content from an element you don't need or want you can add an empty template for that so that it doesn't produce any output (e.g. `<xsl:template match="lg/l[@n]/w[not(@type)]"/>`).

I am not sure whether there is also important white space missing and what are the rules to insert it, you might need to explain that.

Online sample is at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV5/1.

Comment: wonderful! I have looked for hours for a solution when it looks so simple...!! I didn't know `section`. White space missing is not really a problem since there is `<g>`. But maybe with regex, I can add white space. I will look to it and post if I find the correct answer.